# Comparing session variable with get variable PHP

Tags: php, session, get, comparison, integer

I'm trying to compare a `$_SESSION` variable with a `$_GET` variable.

Both are numbers:

```
$_SESSION['auth'] === $_GET['user']
```

If both results equal to 1, then proceed.

For some reason, this is not working correctly. When using: `if $_SESSION['auth'] = 2, and $_GET['user'] = 1`, it still proceeds.

EDIT:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])===isset($_GET['user'])){
// proceeding code
}
```

With this, no matter what the $_GET variable resulted to, it still proceeds. Even if i tried the answer below with (int), it still gives me the same results.

I did try setting $_GET variable to some string to test, that doesn't proceed because my $_SESSION variable is `1`. It only proceeds through code with any number though.

Thanks

Comment: Your code as it is now is invalid.  If you are using an equal-to (strict or not) comparison then you should not be able to proceed as the result would be false, which should cease your code block.  Please post additional code to for better assistance.

Comment: @dagon No, I just didn't insert it in the question to make this simple

Comment: Try to echo the values before your conditional expression to check what the actual output of those variables are.

Comment: @RobB I did echo out values, and it is true that these values are what its supposed to be

Comment: not showing the actual code you are actully using does not make it simple, it makes it meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a function inside a `if` "equal-to" condition, you will be comparing with whatever that function returns.

So in your case, `isset()` returns `true` if the param is set, and `false` otherwise.

That is what you're comparing with, not the values.

It's obvious you want check if the vars are set, before comparing. So do that first, and then begin your comparing. Like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])  && isset($_GET['user'])){

    if($_SESSION['auth'] === (int)$_GET['user'])
    // proceeding code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything coming out of the GET/POST/REQUEST superglobals is typed as a string, even if it consists of only digits. If you stored an actual integer in the SESSION, then your strict comparison (`===`) will fail, because you're comparing a string to an int.

Try

```
$_SESSION['auth'] === (int)$_GET['user']
```

instead, or simply relax the comparison to `==`, which doesn't compare types.

Comment: He said it *does* proceed though, which is why I'm extremely confused with this question, since there's no possible way that would proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing additional code, it seems that you may be using the wrong comparison operator.  The only way that your conditional expression should pass is in the following situation:

```
<?php
$a = 2;

if($a = 1 && $a = 5){
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
?>
```

The usage of `===` is for an identical comparison, for both value and type.  See the docs on the [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for additional reference.

**Update:**

After seeing your code, the reason your conditional expression is passing is because if the result of `isset($_SESSION['auth'])` is `True` and `isset($_GET['user'])` is `True` then it will pass and the same if both are `False`.  Your conditional expression is only checking the result of `isset(VARIABLE)` and not if the variables within matches.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if both `$_SESSION['auth']` and `$_GET['user']` are set or unset, not actually comparing them, try

```
if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])  && isset($_GET['user'])){
    if($_SESSION['auth'] == $_GET['user'])
    // proceeding code
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for the second `if` statement. You can just add the expression to the primary `if` statement: `if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])  && isset($_GET['user']) && $_SESSION['auth'] == $_GET['user']){`.